# How do I use regex to exclude YouTube links?

Tags: php, regex, url

Any idea why this regex not working?

```
'#((http://|www.)(.*^(youtube)\.(com|org|co.il|net|us|ws|info|tv|me|tk|co.uk).*))#'
```

I want to find links that don't belong to YouTube.

Comment: Why not [parse the URL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) properly and check the [second level domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain) from the `PHP_URL_HOST`? I would recommend not creating [2 problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html) for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You have this segment in your regex: `^(youtube)`

Please understand that this will not negate string `youtube`.

You will need negative lookahead or lookbehind to negate matching a text like this:

```
(?!youtube)
```

OR

```
(?<!youtube)
```

For your regex it can be:

```
#((http://|www.)((?!youtube)[^.]+\.(com|org|co.il|net|us|ws|info|tv|me|tk|co.uk).*))#
```

However you need to provide sample of your input strings within your question.

- Read about lookarounds here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: If this answer worked for you then can you mark it as accepted by clicking on tick mark next to this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go the opposite way

```
$youtubePattern = '%(https?:\/\/(www\.)?youtube\.([a-z]{2,3}).*)%six';

if (!preg_match($youtubePattern, $subject)) {
   // not youtube, do whatever...
}
```